# How do I get rid of this unwanted space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I have extra space between my "div class="grid"" (space between the pictures). If you click on "seasonal" and "cups" in my snippet you will know exactly what I mean. I've tried to get rid of this extra space by adding things like "display:none; and clear:both;" on my ".hide" class in css and nothing works. I feel like the problem could be taken care of in js, but I'm not sure how to code it.

Ultimately I'm trying to design a gallery page that a user can sort through images by clicking on the different category items such as "cups" and "clothing and accessories" while keeping a pintrest type style to it because the images are all different sizes. And I'm almost there, but I have this unwanted space on the page.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.category_item').click(function(){
    var category = $(this).attr('id');
    
    if(category == 'all'){
      $('.grid').addClass('hide');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.grid').removeClass('hide');
      }, 300);
    } else {
      $('.grid').addClass('hide');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.' + category).removeClass('hide');
      }, 300);
    }
    
    if(category == 'all'){
      $('.gallery_item').addClass('hide');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.gallery_item').removeClass('hide');
      }, 300);
    } else {
      $('.gallery_item').addClass('hide');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.' + category).removeClass('hide');
      }, 300);
    }
    
  }); 
});
```

```css
/* Gallery */
#gallery_wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 12px 50px 12px 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

#category {
  margin: 40px 0px 20px 0;
}

#category h2 {
  padding-top: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#category h2 {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(20px, 1fr) auto minmax(20px, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

#category h2::before {
  content: '';
  margin-left: 24px;
  border-top: 1px solid;
}

#category h2::after {
  content: '';
  margin-right: 24px;
  border-top: 1px solid;
}

#category ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.category_item {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}   

.hide {
  transform: scale(0);
  width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}

/* Gallery items (pictures, columns, etc.) */
#gallery_item_wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 800px;
  min-width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

#columns {
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-column-fill: auto;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 15px;
  column-fill: auto;
}

.grid {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fefefe;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
  margin: 0 2px 15px;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
  column-break-inside: avoid;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #fff, #f9f9f9);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 250ms ease;
  transition: all 250ms ease;
}

.grid img {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.grid p {
  font: 12px/18px Arial, Helvetica, "sans-serif";
  color: #333;
  margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 560px) {
 #columns {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;}
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
 #columns {
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="category">
    <h2>Gallery</h2>
    <ul>
        <li class="category_item" id="all">All</li>
        <li class="category_item" id="cup">Cups</li>
        <li class="category_item" id="seasonal">Seasonal</li>
        <li class="category_item" id="clothing">Clothing and Accesories</li>
        <li class="category_item" id="misc">Misc</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="gallery_item_wrapper">
    <div id="columns">
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup1.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup2.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid cup seasonal">
            <img src="images/cups/cup3.jpg" class="gallery_item cup seasonal">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup4.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup5.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup6.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
      
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup7.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup9.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup10.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup11.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup13.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup14.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup15.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup16.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup17.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup18.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup19.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup20.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup21.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup22.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup23.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup24.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid seasonal">
            <img src="images/items/a4.jpg" class="gallery_item seasonal">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid seasonal">
            <img src="images/items/a3.jpg" class="gallery_item seasonal">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid seasonal">
            <img src="images/items/a22.jpg" class="gallery_item seasonal">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid seasonal">
            <img src="images/items/a23.jpg" class="gallery_item seasonal">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid seasonal">
            <img src="images/items/a24.jpg" class="gallery_item seasonal">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked a little bit your css, and used flexbox to set the grid. check it out and see if some of this is useful for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.category_item').click(function() {
    var category = $(this).attr('id');

    if (category == 'all') {
      $('.grid').removeClass('hide');
    } else {
      $('.grid').addClass('hide');
      $('.' + category).removeClass('hide');
    }

  });
});
```

```css
/* Gallery */

#gallery_wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 12px 50px 12px 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

#category {
  margin: 40px 0px 20px 0;
}

#category h2 {
  padding-top: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#category h2 {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(20px, 1fr) auto minmax(20px, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

#category h2::before {
  content: '';
  margin-left: 24px;
  border-top: 1px solid;
}

#category h2::after {
  content: '';
  margin-right: 24px;
  border-top: 1px solid;
}

#category ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.category_item {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


/* Gallery items (pictures, columns, etc.) */

#gallery_item_wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 800px;
  min-width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

#columns {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid {
  background: #fefefe;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 15px 5px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #fff, #f9f9f9);
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
  border: 1px solid navy;
  margin: 10px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.grid.hide {
  transform: scale(0);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.grid img {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.grid p {
  font: 12px/18px Arial, Helvetica, "sans-serif";
  color: #333;
  margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 560px) {
  .grid {
    width: calc(33% - 30px);   
  }
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .grid {
    width: calc(25% - 40px);   
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="category">
  <h2>Gallery</h2>
  <ul>
    <li class="category_item" id="all">All</li>
    <li class="category_item" id="cup">Cups</li>
    <li class="category_item" id="seasonal">Seasonal</li>
    <li class="category_item" id="clothing">Clothing and Accesories</li>
    <li class="category_item" id="misc">Misc</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="gallery_item_wrapper">
  <div id="columns">
    <div class="grid cup">
      <img src="images/cups/cup1.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid cup">
      <img src="images/cups/cup2.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid cup seasonal">
      <img src="images/cups/cup3.jpg" class="gallery_item cup seasonal">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid cup">
      <img src="images/cups/cup4.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid cup">
      <img src="images/cups/cup5.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid cup">
      <img src="images/cups/cup6.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid cup">
      <img src="images/cups/cup7.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid cup">
      <img src="images/cups/cup9.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid cup">
      <img src="images/cups/cup10.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid cup">
      <img src="images/cups/cup11.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid cup">
      <img src="images/cups/cup13.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid cup">
      <img src="images/cups/cup14.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid cup">
      <img src="images/cups/cup15.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid cup">
      <img src="images/cups/cup16.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid cup">
      <img src="images/cups/cup17.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid cup">
      <img src="images/cups/cup18.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid cup">
      <img src="images/cups/cup19.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid cup">
      <img src="images/cups/cup20.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid cup">
      <img src="images/cups/cup21.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid cup">
      <img src="images/cups/cup22.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid cup">
      <img src="images/cups/cup23.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid cup">
      <img src="images/cups/cup24.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid seasonal">
      <img src="images/items/a4.jpg" class="gallery_item seasonal">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid seasonal">
      <img src="images/items/a3.jpg" class="gallery_item seasonal">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid seasonal">
      <img src="images/items/a22.jpg" class="gallery_item seasonal">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid seasonal">
      <img src="images/items/a23.jpg" class="gallery_item seasonal">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid seasonal">
      <img src="images/items/a24.jpg" class="gallery_item seasonal">
      <p>Something Cup</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.category_item').click(function(){
    var category = $(this).attr('id');
    
    if(category == 'all'){
      $('.grid').addClass('hide');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.grid').removeClass('hide');
      }, 300);
    } else {
      $('.grid').addClass('hide');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.' + category).removeClass('hide');
      }, 300);
    }
    
    if(category == 'all'){
      $('.gallery_item').addClass('hide');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.gallery_item').removeClass('hide');
      }, 300);
    } else {
      $('.gallery_item').addClass('hide');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.' + category).removeClass('hide');
      }, 300);
    }
    
  }); 
});
```

```css
/* Gallery */
#gallery_wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 12px 50px 12px 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

#category {
  margin: 40px 0px 20px 0;
}

#category h2 {
  padding-top: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#category h2 {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(20px, 1fr) auto minmax(20px, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

#category h2::before {
  content: '';
  margin-left: 24px;
  border-top: 1px solid;
}

#category h2::after {
  content: '';
  margin-right: 24px;
  border-top: 1px solid;
}

#category ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.category_item {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}   

.hide {
  transform: scale(0);
  width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}

/* Gallery items (pictures, columns, etc.) */
#gallery_item_wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 800px;
  min-width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

#columns {
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-column-fill: auto;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 15px;
  column-fill: auto;
}

.grid {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fefefe;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
  margin: 0 2px 15px;
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box; 
column-width: 100px;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
  column-break-inside: avoid;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #fff, #f9f9f9);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 250ms ease;
  transition: all 250ms ease;
}

.grid img {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.grid p {
  font: 12px/18px Arial, Helvetica, "sans-serif";
  color: #333;
  margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 560px) {
 #columns {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;}
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
 #columns {
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="category">
    <h2>Gallery</h2>
    <ul>
        <li class="category_item" id="all">All</li>
        <li class="category_item" id="cup">Cups</li>
        <li class="category_item" id="seasonal">Seasonal</li>
        <li class="category_item" id="clothing">Clothing and Accesories</li>
        <li class="category_item" id="misc">Misc</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="gallery_item_wrapper">
    <div id="columns">
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup1.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup2.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid cup seasonal">
            <img src="images/cups/cup3.jpg" class="gallery_item cup seasonal">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup4.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup5.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup6.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
      
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup7.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup9.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup10.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup11.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup13.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup14.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup15.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup16.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup17.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup18.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup19.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup20.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup21.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup22.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup23.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup24.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid seasonal">
            <img src="images/items/a4.jpg" class="gallery_item seasonal">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid seasonal">
            <img src="images/items/a3.jpg" class="gallery_item seasonal">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid seasonal">
            <img src="images/items/a22.jpg" class="gallery_item seasonal">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid seasonal">
            <img src="images/items/a23.jpg" class="gallery_item seasonal">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid seasonal">
            <img src="images/items/a24.jpg" class="gallery_item seasonal">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome that helped out a lot!  I like the look of the rows better too. I might tweak a few things, but this solved all the problems I've had. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

remove this from CSS, hope it helps:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `width: 100%` and `box-sizing: border-box` to the grid class.

However, I recommend using a proven, battle-tested solution for grids, like the bootstrap grid, or milligram.io, instead of implementing your own from scratch.

Comment: So that did actually work, but not fully. what I mean is there is still empty space, but I can't highlight it like before. [link](http://prntscr.com/ljf20f) (this is before I added width 100% and the border-box) and [link](http://prntscr.com/ljf2f9) (this is after). Next time I'll definitely look into one of the other proven methods, but for now I'm so close and have already devoted a lot of time to this. And thanks for the help so far!

Comment: I see. Another problem you have in your css, is that the .hide class is not being abe to overwrite some of the properties like padding and margin. Try moving the .hide class below the .grid class, or replace .hide with .grid.hide

Comment: It worked!!! thank you so much. I changed ".hide" to ".grid.hide" such a relief to have it working.

Comment: except for now the transition ease-in-out isn't working. there is no transition

Comment: Move the transition property to the grid class and delete it from the .grid.hide selector.

Comment: Yeah I tried to do that and it didn't work. I tried all combinations with the transition property between .grid.hide and just .grid. Meaning I left it in .grid.hide and not in .grid, in both, and just in .grid. The strange thing is.. if I was to change .grid.hide to just ".hide" the transition property works fine on my page. I'm wondering if I have to change something in the js. I would move this discussion into a chat, but I can't yet and I would check your answer, but I'm not sure if this would close the question. hopefully you have a quick solution:)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.category_item').click(function(){
    var category = $(this).attr('id');
    
    if(category == 'all'){
      $('.grid').addClass('hide');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.grid').removeClass('hide');
      }, 300);
    } else {
      $('.grid').addClass('hide');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.' + category).removeClass('hide');
      }, 300);
    }
    
    if(category == 'all'){
      $('.gallery_item').addClass('hide');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.gallery_item').removeClass('hide');
      }, 300);
    } else {
      $('.gallery_item').addClass('hide');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.' + category).removeClass('hide');
      }, 300);
    }
    
  }); 
});
```

```css
/* Gallery */
#gallery_wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 12px 50px 12px 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

#category {
  margin: 40px 0px 20px 0;
}

#category h2 {
  padding-top: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#category h2 {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(20px, 1fr) auto minmax(20px, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

#category h2::before {
  content: '';
  margin-left: 24px;
  border-top: 1px solid;
}

#category h2::after {
  content: '';
  margin-right: 24px;
  border-top: 1px solid;
}

#category ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.category_item {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}   

.hide {
  transform: scale(0);
  width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}

/* Gallery items (pictures, columns, etc.) */
#gallery_item_wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 800px;
  min-width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

#columns {
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-column-fill: auto;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 15px;
  column-fill: auto;
}

.grid {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fefefe;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
  margin: 0 2px 15px;
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box; 
column-width: 100px;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
  column-break-inside: avoid;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #fff, #f9f9f9);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 250ms ease;
  transition: all 250ms ease;
}

.grid img {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.grid p {
  font: 12px/18px Arial, Helvetica, "sans-serif";
  color: #333;
  margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 560px) {
 #columns {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;}
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
 #columns {
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="category">
    <h2>Gallery</h2>
    <ul>
        <li class="category_item" id="all">All</li>
        <li class="category_item" id="cup">Cups</li>
        <li class="category_item" id="seasonal">Seasonal</li>
        <li class="category_item" id="clothing">Clothing and Accesories</li>
        <li class="category_item" id="misc">Misc</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="gallery_item_wrapper">
    <div id="columns">
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup1.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup2.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid cup seasonal">
            <img src="images/cups/cup3.jpg" class="gallery_item cup seasonal">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup4.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup5.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup6.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
      
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup7.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup9.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup10.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup11.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup13.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup14.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup15.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup16.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup17.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup18.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup19.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup20.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup21.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup22.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup23.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid cup">
            <img src="images/cups/cup24.jpg" class="gallery_item cup">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid seasonal">
            <img src="images/items/a4.jpg" class="gallery_item seasonal">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid seasonal">
            <img src="images/items/a3.jpg" class="gallery_item seasonal">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid seasonal">
            <img src="images/items/a22.jpg" class="gallery_item seasonal">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid seasonal">
            <img src="images/items/a23.jpg" class="gallery_item seasonal">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid seasonal">
            <img src="images/items/a24.jpg" class="gallery_item seasonal">
            <p>Something Cup</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```